# Simplify Rails Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to reduce the number of queries in my application and need some help with the following setup:

I have 5 models:

- Bet
- Choice
- Spotprice
- Spotarea
- Product

They are associated with the following:

- Bet belongs_to Choice
- Choice belongs_to Spotarea
- Choice belongs_to Product
- Choice has_many Bets
- Spotprice belongs_to Spotarea
- Spotprice belongs_to Product
- Spotarea has_many Spotprices
- Spotarea has_many Choices
- Product has_many Sprotprices
- Product has_many Choices

My goal is to find the Spotprices that matches a Specific Bet. To do that I uses the following queries, but I'm sure it can be done in a better way, so when I run through 100 bets and want to see if they are above or below the corrosponding Spotprice I don't overload the DB with queries.

```
a = Bet.find(5)

b = Choice.find(a.choice_id)

c = Spotprice.where(:spotarea_id => b.spotarea_id, :product_id => b.product_id, 
    :deliverydate => b.deliverydate).first
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours and a lot of Google search I found a solution that works.. After adding the join bridges I wanted to do:

```
Bet.find(5).spotprice
```

But that didn't work because to do that I needed something like this in my Choice model:

```
has_one :spotprice, :through => [:spotarea, :product] :source => :spotprices
```

I that is not possible.. apperently..

So I found this link [has_one :through => multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976852/has-one-through-multiple) and I could use that answer in my situation.

```
class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :spotarea
  belongs_to :product
  has_many   :bets

  def spotprice
    Spotprice.where(:product_id => self.product_id, :spotarea_id => self.spotarea_id, :deliverydate => self.deliverydate).first
  end

class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :choice
  has_one    :spotprice, :through => :choice
```

With the above I can now do:

```
Bet.find(5).choice.spotprice
```

If anybody got a better solution please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

first of all, set up join bridges:

```
class Choice
  has_many :spotprices, :through => :spotarea
end

class Bet
  has_many :spotprices, :through => :choice
end
```

then you can query things like

```
Bet.joins(:spotprices).where("spotprices.price > bets.value")
```

Comment: Thanks.. The join bridges sure helped, but still didn't fix the problem entirely.. I've posted an answer with the solution.. Thanks for the help to guide me in the right direction..

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to decrease the number of queries, you should run a performance test on your app, and monitor the database load. Sometimes it's better to run a few small queries rather than one huge query with a few joins. Certain versions of Oracle seem especially bad at joins.

An alternative to joins, if you're trying to avoid the n+1 query problem, is to use `preload` and pass the association (`preload` takes the same arguments as `includes`). This makes ActiveRecord run one query per table.

Basically:

1. you always want to avoid the n+1 problem.
2. trying to combine multiple queries into a join could in the best case be a premature optimization, and in the worst case actually make performance worse.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.. I'm surely going to look into the `preload` thing and try to avoid the n+1 problems.. which I had to look up cause I didn't know what you ment :)

Answer (score 0):

Well here's one pretty easy change:

```
b = Bet.includes(:choice).find(5).choice
```

Comment: :includes does a separate query and joins in ruby. Use :joins to make a real join

Comment: That's not entirely true.  It sometimes does an extra query and sometimes doesn't.